# Multiple vertical edges in Notepad++

Tags: coding-style, notepad++

In Settings->Preferences->Editing you can show a vertical edge to indicate a column width which you don't want to exceed.

I've currently got one at 80 characters, but I'd also like to add one at 120 characters as the coding standards I'm adhering to have different line limits for different languages. However, I can't seem to find either a native setting or a plugin which enables me to have multiple vertical edges (the cherry on the cake would be to have them in different colours as well).

I've done an extensive search online but don't seem to be able to find anything. Has anyone else found a way to do this?

Comment: necroposting: see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1032940/notepad-how-to-display-multiple-vertical-lines) question with answer